# String index out of range in for each loop

Tags: python, string, indexing

My code glitches at the point its learning a letter in the code

````
while not cracked:
   Word = "" # Word auto generates to learn a word
   for element in range(0, len(WordLearning)):
       print(element)
       if(element in LettersItKnows):
           Word = Word + WordLearning[element]
       else:
           if(Word[element] == WordLearning[element]): # Right Here it is weird
               LettersItKnows.append(element)
           else:
               Word = Word + random.choice(Letters) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `len()` returns the number of elements in a list. but when you're getting an element from a list like this: `myList[3]` the first element is `0` which means that you need to do this:

````
while not cracked:
    Word = "" # Word auto generates to learn a word
    for element in range(len(WordLearning) - 1):
        print(element)
        if(element in LettersItKnows):
            Word = Word + WordLearning[element]
        else:
            if(Word[element] == WordLearning[element]): # Right Here it is weird
                LettersItKnows.append(element)
            else:
                Word = Word + random.choice(Letters) ```
````

You can see that all I did here was replace this: `range(0, len(WordLearning))` by this: `range(len(WordLearning) - 1)` I got rid of the `0,` because the `range()` starts on zero by default

Note that in this script if you reach this line: `if(Word[element] == ...` you'll get might get an error because there is a chance that the Word variable will still equal this: `""` so you might fix that problem by setting `Word` to something that has more letters than the number of elements in the `WordLearning` variable. I can't really help you though because I don't understand anything about your script

Comment: Won’t this code also fail as soon as an element not in LettersItKnows is found

Comment: Oh yeah. I don't know how would that be fixed though because I don't understand anything about this script. The person making this script should be able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This code will fail as soon as an character not in `LettersItKnows` is found, because the length of `Word` will then be equal to `element`, so `Word[element]`, the `element + 1`th element of `Word`, will not exist.